# Cannot read property call of undefined at Blockly.Generator.blockToCode

Tags: blockly

I am trying to add a custom text block. But when i enter any text in the input field, the error comes up. 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

```
Blockly.Blocks['text_input']={
init:function()
 {
 this.appendDummyInput()
 .appendField('Text Input:')
 .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput(''),'INPUT');   
 this.setColour(170);
 this.setOutput(true);    
 }  
};
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

this happens when the language definition for your custom type is missing.

```
// Replace "JavaScript" with the language you use.
Blockly.JavaScript['text_input'] = function(block) {
  var value = Blockly.JSON.valueToCode(block, 'INPUT', Blockly.JavaScript.ORDER_NONE);

  // do something useful here
  var code = 'var x= "bananas"';
  return code;
};
```

Comment: BTW you can generate that code from the blockly demo page too. Select the "Block Exporter" tab and download the "Generator Stubs"

Comment: Thanks.. Ya the definition was missing.

Comment: I have checked my language definition and its JavaScript only. But still I am getting this error.

Comment: @YashKochar open a question and explain your problem, including code.